# IIS - .NET Core api not starting when deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-devops, application-pool

I use VSTS to deploy my app

I have set the "put app offline" option to avoid intermittent access failure when deploying

**the problem is that my app (.NET Core 3.1 API) is not starting automatically**

I tried a couple of settings in IIS application pool but nothing works

```
1 Start Mode > Always Running
2 Advanced Settings > Preload Enabled > True
3 Idle Time-out > 0
```

I tried using this command line after the deployment

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:"my-application-pool"
```

although the command runs fine, **the app is sill not launched**

**I have to login on the angular front end for the api to launch and start populating the logs**

am I missing something ?

thanks for helping me, let me know if you need more infos